# How to XML serialize child class with its base class

Tags: c#, .net

I am able to serialize a single type/class but is there a way that I can serialize it base class too?

For example:

```
class B:A
```

Here I am able to serialize class B but how can I serialize class A ?

Comment: What is exactly not serializing from the base class? Can you be more precise.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Have you tried `base.Serialize()`?

Comment: Its simple question, if I am serializing a child class, I want its base class also should get serialized with it.

Comment: Even if it is a simple question you fail to express it in a precise way. What is "serialize with it" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`A` must know in advance, i.e.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(B))]
public class A {...}


public class B {...}
```

Now a `new XmlSerializer(typeof(A))`  can serialize an `A` or a `B`. You can also do this *without* attributes by passing in a `extraTypes` parameter to the overloaded `XmlSerializer` constructor, but again - the root should be `A`; i.e. `new XmlSeralializer(typeof(A), new[] {typeof(B)})`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague.

You could just cast your object to the base class when serializing, however when you do that you need to provide the sub-types that A can assume when creating a serializer (`new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass), ExtraTypesGoHere);`), or you use `[XmlInclude(Type type)]` in the classes that may have properties exposing objects of those sub-types.