# Serialization of parent object

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to serialize parent object like in this example

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Child child = new Child
            {
                Id = 5,
                Name = "John",
                Address = "Address"
            };

        Parent parent = child;

        XmlSerializer serializer =new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parent));
        Stream stream=new MemoryStream();

        serializer.Serialize(stream,parent); //this line throws exception 

        Parent p2 = (Parent) serializer.Deserialize(stream);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Child : Parent
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

The exception text that I'm getting is "The type CastParrentExample.Child was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."
What I'm trying to reach is to get true Parent class object without Child class fields.

Comment: You're not getting a 'true' Parent object by assigning the reference. You would have to create a new Parent object and assign its properties from the corresponding properties in the Child object. Better do it by hand than by XML serialization, not that it is easy to make the XML serializer ignore the actual type of the serialized object (specified in XML via xsi:type) on deserialization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to XML serialize child class with its base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943360/how-to-xml-serialize-child-class-with-its-base-class)

Comment: "You would have to create a new Parent object and assign its properties from the corresponding properties in the Child object." Can you recommend an easy way to do this for a huge class ? Reflection maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `[XmlInclude(typeof(Child))]` to parent class, as:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Child))]
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

or use following code while initializing XmlSeralializer:

```
XmlSerializer serializer =new XmlSeralializer(typeof(Parent), new[] {typeof(Child)})
```

for better understanding, see [How to XML serialize child class with its base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943360/how-to-xml-serialize-child-class-with-its-base-class).

Answer (score 2):

At the Parent class add attribute

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Child))]
class Parent {
...
```