# Deserialize XML to a list of objects that share the same base class

Tags: c#, list, serialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I'm using c#. I have a base class, we'll call `BaseClass`.  I have three other classes that derive from `BaseClass`.  I have a `List<BaseClass>` that contains different instances of the derived classes. I serialize this list to XML using the `XmlSerializer` and it looks fine.

However, when I try to deserialize the XML back to the objects, I'm getting XML exception errors thrown pointing to the first object.

How can I deserialize this list of objects? When I serialize it, I pass the possible types, do I need to set this when I deserialize so the deserialize method knows what objects it could possibly have to create?  Is there another way? Is it possible?

Comment: And what is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `XmlInclude` attribute to specify all the subclasses of the base class.  See [How to XML serialize child class with its base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943360/how-to-xml-serialize-child-class-with-its-base-class) or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx